# Returning full statement with join in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using the SQLalchemy table declaration to avoid using strings and manually generating SQL statements. This has worked quite well, except for the following use case where I'm trying to return a statement which creates a merged table with all columns from both tables, joined on an implicit PK/FK which exists between the tables.

It seems like the statement below only selects columns from the first (Result) table and I'm not sure how to generate the full select statement?

```
sql = Query(Results, Details).join(Details)\
            .filter(Details.result_type == 'standard')\
            .statement
```

Answer (score 0):

The query construct isn't the best to use for this use case, as it will return the objects themselves. Instead, this can be done with the select construct as follows:

```
sql = select([Results, Details])\
        .select_from(Results.join(Details))
```